# How is one expected to use open sockets with [delimited] continuations?

Tags: continuation

I'm trying to figure out how an open socket or file handle should interact with continuations. Searching has revealed that `dynamic-wind` is probably part of the solution, but I'm more interested in the methodology rather than the implementation, and all I could find is how to implement it under various conditions.

Do programmers even use sockets within continuations in such a way that it is necessary for `dynamic-wind` to close them? Or is it typically just a way to implement a "finally" block if the continuation exits past where the socket is handled?

What should happen if a continuation is re-entered after a hypothetical `dynamic-wind` closes the socket?

Comment: Is the question about a specific language? Scheme, Clojure? In such a case, consider adding an extra tag to make your question more focused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is common to automatically close files, sockets, and other resources when the program uses a continuation (or exception, which is often implemented using continuations) to exit a context. There are often library procedures that help do this automatically; for example, see Racket's [call-with-input-file*](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/file-ports.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._call-with-input-file*%29%29), [call-with-semaphore](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/semaphore.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._call-with-semaphore%29%29), etc. They all use `dynamic-wind` in their implementation.

It's often difficult to write code that uses or manages resources correctly in the presence of continuations. For example, if a file gets closed when control jumps out, should it be re-opened when control jumps back in? If so, maybe it needs to be opened in a different mode the second time, eg append instead of truncate. But now it may be difficult to ensure that the output is well-formed; continuation jumps may mean that parts get written multiple times, out of order, etc. And so on. So it's often useful to simply prohibit continuation jumps back into a context once it's been exited. Racket provides [`call-with-continuation-barrier`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/cont.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._call-with-continuation-barrier%29%29) for this purpose, but it can also be done with `dynamic-wind` and a mutable variable.

(One difference between using `call-with-continuation-barrier` and `dynamic-wind` is that you use `call-with-continuation-barrier` around your call to unknown code, whereas `dynamic-wind` would need to be around the *beginning* of the code that you want to protect from reentry, which may be harder to determine. There's a [mailing-list post](https://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2010-July/040393.html) with more detailed discussion.)

The story is about the same for delimited continuations. For example, `shift` jumps out across boundaries, and applying the procedure it gives you jumps in across the captured context boundaries.